# Terraform - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority - getting IP address

Tags: azure, terraform, ssl-certificate, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In order to deploy our Terraform configuration we use the following data block to grab the IP of the machine that is running TF which is required for remote execution:

```
data "http" "tf_ip" { # Gets the IP of the machine that is running TF (will be required for remote execution)
  url = "https://ipv4.icanhazip.com"
}
```

This was working perfectly fine for me, until I downgraded my WSL version from 2 to 1 (due to VPN issues with WSL2).

However now I receive this error when running my plan:

```
│ Error: Error making request: Get "https://ipv4.icanhazip.com": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
│
│   with data.http.tf_ip,
│   on main.data.tf line 1, in data "http" "tf_ip":
│    1: data "http" "tf_ip" { # Gets the IP of the machine that is running TF (will be required for remote execution)
```

Also this appears to work for others who are using WSL1 - so I'm not entirely sure what the issue is as we've never had to install any CA certificates for this previously.

I know there is a workaround involving adding and Insecure = true flag to the data block, but would like to avoid that if possible as it would have to be reverted before every commit.

Any help would be appreciated.